# nodeforge cert.setSubject : Attribute type is not specified

Tags: javascript, node.js, pki, node-forge

New to typescript, and I am working with nodeforge to generate CA and I do not know how to resolve this error.

PS: Vscode did not show red underline, but nextjs throws the error.

```
    const cert = pki.createCertificate();
    const attrs = [
      { name: 'commonName', value: 'My First CA' },
      { name: 'organizationUnitName', value: 'Organization Unit' },
      { name: 'organizationName', value: 'My Organization' },
    ] //this is returned by buildSubjectFromOptions

    cert.setSubject(attrs as pki.CertificateField[]);
    cert.setIssuer(attrs as pki.CertificateField[]);
```

At the last 2 lines, I am getting the error **Attribute type is not specified**, even though I followed vs code instructions as below

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think i had this issue after adding "organizationUnitName". Without it it worked fine. "organizationUnitName" cannot be found in node-forge code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this similar issue as well. I looked at the X509.js and oids.js library files of node-forge.

oids.js:

```
_IN('2.5.4.10', 'organizationName')
_IN('2.5.4.10', 'organizationName')
```

X509.js:

```
_shortNames['OU'] = oids['organizationalUnitName'];
_shortNames['organizationalUnitName'] = 'OU';
```

It seems that your attribute "organizationUnitName" is actually stored in pki.oids/x509.js as "organizationalUnitName". If you fix your typo from  "organizationUnitName" to "organizationalUnitName" should hopefully resolve the issue.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

So I went to code of node-forge where the error was called, as follows

```
// populate missing type (OID)
if(typeof attr.type === 'undefined') {
  if(attr.name && attr.name in pki.oids) {
    attr.type = pki.oids[attr.name];
  } else {
    var error = new Error('Attribute type not specified.');
    error.attribute = attr;
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Even though my attributes exists in pki.oids, i don't know why it still throws the error.

I amended my attributes format to as follows,adding the key `type` and now error goes away.

```
  const attrs = [
      { name: 'commonName', value: 'My First CA', type: 'commonName' },
      { name: 'organizationUnitName', value: 'Organization Unit', type: 'organizationUnitName' },
      { name: 'organizationName', value: 'My Organization', type: 'organizationName' },
    ]
```